# Web user input form and passing its contents to python selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have one very general question and another a bit more specific.

Let's start with the general one as it is strictly connected with the second one.

So I'd like to create a website (internal, not available on the internet) with a form that validates user input and if it doesn't meet certain criteria- it cannot be submitted.

Does it make sense to create this website (and form) with python django? I mean- obviously it has a lot of sense but there is something else I am trying to puzzle out here:

Will it make possible to get user input from this website form and pass it to python selenium script?

I am trying to figure this out as I'd like to improve ordering process with which I work. It is done with a web application provided by an external provider (all things that happen in this application are automatized with python selenium).

For the time being I have to read order form (mostly scanned paper forms, pdfs and faxes) put data to excel and then get them to python selenium script but I would like to stop using excel (as it can be really messy). I have to use excel as an intermediary as I don't have a working OCR (so I am an OCR in this case :)) plus current order forms are very different from one another (and standardization is not an option).

Is it even possible? Is the way I am thinking about anywhere near common sense? Maybe there is an easier method? Any ideas? Thanks for all advices and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty broad, but definitely possible. I would use Flask personally. You can pass any data easily from a form to python and execute any python code on that data with a simple Flask website.

Comment: Could you recommend any tutorials for form validation with Flask?

Comment: http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/forms.html and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/